# how to do cauchy product of sums

Tags: real-analysis, summation

For example, how to do cauchy product of $$\ln(1-x)*\ln (1-x)=\ln ^2 (1-x)$$

should it go like this?

$$\ln(1-x)=-\sum_{k=1}^{k=\infty}\frac{x^{k}}{k}$$
$$\ln ^2 (1-x)=\sum_{n=1}^{n=\infty}x^{n}\sum_{k=1}^{k=n}\frac{1}{k(n-k)}$$
Here , when n=k its 1/0 , how to fix this?

Also, for example, how ot find $$\arctan ^2(x)$$. thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When doing the series multiplication we can perform the cauchy multiplication as usual, but we have to carefully consider the index limits. We obtain

\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{\ln^2(1-x)}&=\left(-\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{x^k}{k}\right)\tag{1}
\left(-\sum_{l=1}^\infty \frac{x^l}{l}\right)\\
&=\sum_{n=2}^\infty\left(\sum_{\substack{k+l=n\\k,l\geq 1}}\frac{1}{k}\,\frac{1}{l}\right)x^n\tag{2}\\
&\,\,\color{blue}{=\sum_{n=2}^\infty\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{k(n-k)}\right)x^n}\tag{3}\\
\end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (1) we see the  indices $k,l$ of both series start with lower limit $1$, so that $x^2$ is the term with the smallest positive exponent.
- In (2) we collect the terms according to increasing powers of $n$. So, we consider indices $k+l=n$, but we also have to respect that $k,l\geq 1$ by explicitly noting it and we also start with lower index limit $n=2$.
- In (3) we replace $l$ by $n-k$. Since both, $l,k\geq 1$ we have lower index limit $k=1$ and upper limit $k=n-1$.

Comment: we start with n=2 cuz we have the lowest x*x . then we need to move it to n-1 to be sure (n-k) is not zero. is that right?

Comment: @VukStojiljkovic: The upper limit $n-1$ of the inner sum follows solely from $k+l=n$ and $k,l\geq 1$. Since *both*, $k$ and $l$ are $\geq 1$ it follows from $k+l=n$ that $1\leq k\leq n-1$. We do not need to change the index $n$ of the outer sum.

Comment: but we could also say that $1<=l<= n-1$ , right? We just need to satisfy the condition?

Comment: @VukStojiljkovic: Correct. Looking at (2) we see the inner sum is symmetric with respect to $k$ and $l$. Consequently, we can replace $k$ with $l$ in (3).

Comment: thank you for your help :)

Comment: @VukStojiljkovic: You're welcome! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Cauchy product of $\sum_0^\infty a_n x^n $ with $\sum_0^\infty b_n x^n $ is $\sum_0^\infty c_n x^n $ where $c_n=\sum_{k+l=n} a_k b_l$. To apply this formula you should "pad the series" with a zero at the zeroth term:
$$\ln(1-x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n, \quad a_n= \begin{cases} 0 & n=0 \\ -1/n & n>0\end{cases}.$$
Then
$ \ln^2(1-x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n x^n$ with
$$ c_n = \sum_{k+l=n} a_k a_l=\sum_{\substack{k+l=n \\ k>0\text{ and }l>0}} a_k a_l + \underbrace{\sum_{\substack{k+l=n \\ k=0\text{ or }l=0}} a_k a_l}_{=0}=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \frac1{k(n-k)}$$

Comment: did you mean 1/n when n>0? And, do i do such thing every time i do cauchy product? i mean, $$\sum_{k+l=n}a_{k}a_{l}=\sum_{k+l=n, k>0\land l>0}a_{k}a_{l}+\sum_{k+l=n,k=0or l=0}a_{k}a_{l}=...$$ i mean, do i decompose it into the part when both are  >0 and when one of them is 0. Also, whats the problem with the way i did it? Or is it just fine and i should fix it every time when i see it will be 1/0 with it going up to n-1 as you did.? Thank you.

Comment: Oh, its -1/n cuz its ln(1-x) , but see other things i wrote. please. thank you.

Comment: @VukStojiljkovic Cauchy product formula (at least, the one I was taught) requires that your series begins from zero. The problem is you were not careful and therefore found a 1/0. It’s not enough to do that, what if the series started at $n=3$? Then you need to go to $n-3$. Better to actually learn why it is correct IMO